# Adding groupcheckboxinput values to data frame in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I am attempting to add the values from a checkboxgroupinput value to the data frame called surv_data in a Shiny App.

Below is the code for the check boxes:

```
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "variables", label = "",
                         choices = c(
                           "Covariate 1" = "cov1",
                           "Covariate 2" = "cov2"
                         ),
                         selected = c('cov1', 'cov2'))
```

Here is where I combine the variables in to one data frame:

```
  surv_data <- reactive({
    raw_surv <- raw_surv_data()
    data.frame(
      Time = raw_surv[[input$Time]],
      Treatment    = raw_surv[[input$Treatment]],
      endpoint  = raw_surv[[input$Endpoint]]
    )
  })
```

I need to somehow add the values cov1 and cov2 below the following line:

```
endpoint  = raw_surv[[input$Endpoint]]
```

I've attempted to add `variables = raw_surv[[input$variables]]` but unfortunately this does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
surv_data <- reactive({
  raw_surv <- raw_surv_data()
  cbind(
    data.frame(
      Time = raw_surv[[input$Time]],
      Treatment = raw_surv[[input$Treatment]],
      endpoint = raw_surv[[input$Endpoint]]
    ),
    raw_surv[input$variables]
  )
})
```